# AWS Classis Load Balancer access logs return empty fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, nginx-ingress

We have a few classic load balancers that are setup by an nginx ingress controller in EKS.
We're trying to setup the access logs via S3 for the load balancers. We have setup the access logs but when we check the entries in S3, this is what we get :

```
2023-04-11T00:03:19.768961Z <LB-NAME-RETURNS-FINE> <CLIENTIP:PORT> - -1 -1 -1 - - 0 0 "- - - " "-" - -
```

Checking the AWS Documentation this is all the fields that access logs should return :

```
timestamp elb client:port backend:port request_processing_time backend_processing_time response_processing_time elb_status_code backend_status_code received_bytes sent_bytes "request" "user_agent" ssl_cipher ssl_protocol
```

We're interested in seeing "request" and elb_status_code but they return empty everytime when we do know they're not empty.

What could the issue be here, perhaps a misconfiguration on the ingress controller, I'm not sure what to check.

Comment: Did you ever get insight into this? I'm experiencing the same issue.